# App delegate: unrecognised selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, appdelegate

I've got some code in my app delegate method that is supposed to send an object to a view controller. For some reason though it is throwing an error : "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

in the view controller I have the following variable set:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Patient* patient;
```

the code in my app delegate looks like this:

```
    UISplitViewController* splitViewController = (UISplitViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController* patientNavController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
PatientMasterTableViewController* patientMasterTableViewController = (PatientMasterTableViewController*)[patientNavController topViewController];
PatientDetailViewController* patientDetailViewController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

Patient* firstPatient = [[patientMasterTableViewController patientArray] objectAtIndex:0];
[patientDetailViewController setPatient:firstPatient];// this line throwing the error
```

I am new to iOS and I don't quite understand why it won't allow me to pass the patient object. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you set the property in the header file?

Comment: Add the details of the exception you are getting - it will tell you what the selector was and what object type you tried to send it to.  This will enable you to work out where you have gone wrong

Comment: The details of the exception:

UINavigationController setPatient:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8fa1380
2014-10-19 15:58:08.136 ORA[946:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setPatient:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8fa1380'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code:

```
PatientDetailViewController* patientDetailViewController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Is not guaranteed to return a `PatientDetailViewController`. It can return an object of any class, and you are not checking what class of object is returned.

Your app is crashing because it's returning a `UINavgationController` object, which does not have a `setPatient` method.

As for why it's returning an object of the wrong class, that will depend what view controllers you have created.

Answer (score 0):

You have bug in your code - look at this two lines:

UINavigationController* patientNavController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

PatientDetailViewController* patientDetailViewController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

array splitViewController.viewControllers contains only ONE ! element in portrait mode and TWO elements in landscape mode. DetailsViewController always is in this array but master does not: in portrait mode array contains only detail view ctrl and in landscape the array is @[master,details]

so if You want always to get DetailViewController use this code

[[splitViewController viewControllers] lastObject];